# How to solve opencv_highgui_gtk453_64.dll issue?

Tags: c++, opencv

When I install opencv-4.5.3, I find some problems with it.

```
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\highgui\src\registry.impl.hpp (114) cv::highgui_backend::UIBackendRegistry::UIBackendRegistry UI: Enabled backends(4, sorted by priority): GTK(1000); GTK3(990); GTK2(980); WIN32(970) + BUILTIN(WIN32UI)
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\opencv_highgui_gtk453_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_highgui_gtk453_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\opencv_highgui_gtk3453_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_highgui_gtk3453_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\opencv_highgui_gtk2453_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_highgui_gtk2453_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\highgui\src\backend.cpp (90) cv::highgui_backend::createUIBackend UI: using backend: WIN32 (priority=970)
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp (3009) cv::impl::Win32BackendUI::createWindow OpenCV/UI: Creating Win32UI window: picture (1)
```

Answer (score 4):

So these messages are just "INFO" messages. Release will not showing them as mentionned above due to debug level being higher. These error messages seem to be always there, you can ignore them :)

see more info here :
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20113

Answer (score 0):

Use release instead of debug, then you won't see these messages.